# Embed User related SharePoint List Form in SharePoint Online Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, modern-experience

We have a SharePoint List in SharePoint Online holding max 1 element per User. 
Everyone can add only one element with his wanted settings. After that he is just able to edit his element.

[image]

The form was edited with PowerApps.

[image]

**Now I want to embed this form in a SharePoint Modern Site. If there is no element in that list for the current user the form should be a "NewForm". When there is an element in that list it should be the "EditForm".**

Hope to find help. Any questions will be answered! Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your discription, my understand that you want to remove user "add items" permssion after the user create a item. You could achieve this with flow.

Create a permission level exclude the add items permission. Then use flow to grant the user  this permission level when an item is created. You could refer to this video about how to change persmission with flow:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-vvlPXv8rc

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It is possible to set the permissions with flow. Do you have any idea how to embed the form in SPO Modern pages - in a way that people not having used the form ever see the "NewForm" to enter their data and people that have entered data in the past see the "EditForm" to change their data?

Comment: Hi. If a user do not have add an item permission. He would not see the "EditForm" link. So in my workaround, after the user creat an item, remove his "add an item" permission.